# Saving the items of a listbox to a text file

Tags: c#, listbox, text-files

How can I save the contents of my `listbox` items to a text file using a `SaveFileDialog`?

I also want to add additional information to the text file and also add a `MessageBox` saying saved when it's been successful.

Comment: @roller - has this been resolved?

Answer (score 4):

```
        var saveFile = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFile.Filter = "Text (*.txt)|*.txt";
        if (saveFile.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(saveFile.FileName, false))
                foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
                    sw.Write(item.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
            MessageBox.Show("Success");
        }
```

Also take note the `StreamWriter` has a Type of [Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3aadshsx.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336186/saving-listbox-items-to-file?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

this should do it.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog f = new OpenFileDialog();

    f.ShowDialog();                 

    ListBox l = new ListBox();
    l.Items.Add("one");
    l.Items.Add("two");
    l.Items.Add("three");
    l.Items.Add("four");

    string textout = "";

    // assume the li is a string - will fail if not
    foreach (string li in l.Items)
    {
        textout = textout + li + Environment.NewLine;
    }

    textout = "extra stuff at the top" + Environment.NewLine + textout + "extra stuff at the bottom";
    File.WriteAllText(f.FileName, textout);

    MessageBox.Show("all saved!");
}
```

Comment: `OpenFileDialog`? or `SaveFileDialog`?

Answer (score 1):

A `SaveFileDialog` is used with `ShowDialog()` to show it to the user, and if it's successful, using its `OpenFile()` to get the (File)`Stream` that you write to.  There's an example on the [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfezx97z.aspx).

A `ListBox` can be accessed through its `Items` property, which is simply a collection of the items on it.

Answer (score 0):

To Save

```
   // fetch the selected Text from your list
   string textToRight = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();  

   // Write to a file       
   StreamWriter sr = File.CreateText(@"testfile.txt");       
   sr.Write(textToRight);
   sr.Close();
```

Message

```
   // display Message
   MessageBox.Show( "Information Saved Successfully" );
```

Comment: **You forgot to close your StreamWriter**.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few things going on there - make sure you split them up, e.g.

- Get list box contents
- Append Info
- Write File

**Please note!!** There is a myriad of exceptions you can get while saving a file, see the docs and handle them somehow...

```
// Get list box contents
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var item in lstBox.Items)
{
    // i am using the .ToString here, you may do more
    sb.AppendLine(item);
}
string data = sb.ToString();

// Append Info
data = data + ????....

// Write File
void Save(string data)
{
    using(SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog())
    {
        // optional
        saveFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer);

        //saveFileDialog.Filter = ???;

        if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog.Filename);
            MessageBox.Show("ok", "all good etc");
        }
        else
        {
        // not good......
        }
    }
}
```