# Saving listbox items to file

Tags: c#

I am trying to save the items from a listbox to a file. So I started writing this code:

```
private void mstri_SaveLog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Stream s;
  this.sfd_Log.Filter = "Textfiles (*.txt)|*.txt";
  DialogResult d = this.sfd_Log.ShowDialog();
  if ((d == DialogResult.OK) && (this.lb_Log.Items.Count != 0))
  {
      for (int i = 0; i < this.lb_Log.Items.Count; i++)
      {
          if ((s = this.sfd_Log.OpenFile()) != null)
          {
              StreamWriter wText = new StreamWriter(s);
              wText.Write(this.lb_Log.Items[i]);
              s.Close();
          } 
      }
  }
}
```

There is a new textfile that is created, but it is **always empty**. But I have no idea where there is a mistake in my code.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two problems that are causing the file to be blank.  The first problem is that the StreamWriter is buffering up data and is not writing that data to the file.  A simple call to wText.Flush() will solve this.

The second problem is that everytime the StreamWriter is closed and reopened, it is starting at the beginning of the file, effectively clearing out whatever you had written to it in the previous iteration.  Opening and closing the StreamWriter should occur outside the for-loop.

Here's how i would do it:

```
Stream s;
this.sfd_Log.Filter = "Textfiles (.txt)|.txt";
DialogResult d = this.sfd_Log.ShowDialog();
if ((d == DialogResult.OK) && (this.lb_Log.Items.Count != 0))
{
    if ((s = this.sfd_Log.OpenFile()) != null)
    {
        StreamWriter wText = new StreamWriter(s);
        for (int i = 0; i < this.lb_Log.Items.Count; i++)
        {

            wText.Write((this.lb_Log.Items[i]));

        }
        wText.Flush();
        s.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, great explanation, but now there's another problem.
The items are now written in a row to the textfile like: abcd, but I want to have it like
a \n. I hope you understand what I mean.
b \n
c \n
d \n

Comment: @Forlan07: Use `WriteLine` rather than `Write`.

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
  if ((d == DialogResult.OK) && (this.lb_Log.Items.Count != 0))
  {
      for (int i = 0; i < this.lb_Log.Items.Count; i++)
      {
          if ((s = this.sfd_Log.OpenFile()) != null)
          {

            using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(s)
            {
                outfile.Write(this.lb_Log.Items[i]);
             }


          } 
      }

      s.Close();
  }
```

Comment: When I use this function, only the last entry of my listbox is written to the file.

Comment: @Slider pointed out why: s.Close() was the culprit. I fixed it.. at least, I think I fixed it. I haven't tested

Comment: Why not utilize 'using' for both the stream opened by OpenFile as well as the StreamWriter?  That way you can guarantee that it will be closed even if an exception is thrown in the middle of the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a version of the .NET framework new enough to have the LINQ extension methods (I believe 3.0 and newer), you can do something like this:

```
if ((d == DialogResult.OK) && (this.lb_Log.Items.Count != 0))
{
     File.WriteAllLines(d.FileName, this.lb_Log.Items.Cast<String>());
}
```